# Fetch metadata from shared files without oauth2.0 on Google Drive

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api

The IDE I am using is Eclipse 4.2 Juno. I have no compile or import errors. Here is the code I am currently using (some is blatantly copied from the tutorials, some is adapted, some I have no clue where it came from):

```
public static void print()
{

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    Drive serv = new Drive(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null);
    try {
    File f = serv.files().get("1K5Ge9-Rz_L2gJH5hKrpkAfFDos5ZgRCvnzy7_HaiAV8").execute();

    System.out.println(f.getId());


        //System.out.println(f.getDownloadUrl());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The error is on the line with "File f = ...". I get 403 usage limit errors. Looking at the code, this is to be expected because it does not authenticate as per the requirements in Google's documentation.

The application is a simple executable .jar that fetches content from various sources (in this case google drive) and then calls an outside program to convert it. If I can get a hold of the document's metadata, I can use it to better serve the user. BUT, the content must be made public. So how can I get the data from a document's link without asking for the user's personal information or opening their web browser? Yes, I have an API key.

I know it can work because the proof of concept [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it) gives me the option of using OAuth2.0 or not. For the record I am currently migrating from Documents list.

*EDIT*
It only makes sense that I would figure it out less than 5 minutes after posting this question. I just have to construct a URL that looks like this "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/*document_id*?key=*key* and I can get all the data I want.

New question, is it wise to place my key in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can retrieve metadata for files stored on Google Drive if you don't authorize your requests using OAuth 2.0.

Instead of an API key, you need to create a project in the APIs Console and generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for your application before you can send authorized requests.

Once you perform the OAuth flow and obtain an access token, you can use it to retrieve documents' metadata. An easy way to get started with the Google Drive SDK is the quickstart at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart, it will guide you from the project creation to a complete command-line application that uploads a file to Drive.